# SecurityException - Dapper on shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, shared-hosting, dapper, securityexception

For my current project I use Dapper. Everything perfect. Then I needed to deploy it on shared hosting. The result can be seen here (copied YSOD):

> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Stack trace

> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.]    System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission
>   cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
>   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.PerformSecurityCheck(Type owner,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean skipVisibility) +9461551
>   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(String name, Type
>   returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner, Boolean skipVisibility)
>   +40    Dapperx.SqlMapper.CreateParamInfoGenerator(Identity identity) +537    Dapperx.SqlMapper.GetCacheInfo(Identity identity) +376    Dapperx.d__13`1.MoveNext() +644
>
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +327
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>   Dapperx.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param,
>   IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) +199
>   ...

Is there any way how to solve it for (in .NET 4.0)?
As far as I understand what I've read so far, the provider has to allow some parts from reflection for the IIS which might be a security risk for them...

Comment: I cannot see a way of making "dapper" work without that permission :(

Comment: @MarcGravell I found "code ffrom the GAC always runs in full trust" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87x8e4d1), so if I persuade them to install Dapper to GAC, the problem is gone, right? Besides that.. you might distribute Dapper with strong name. Otherwise people have to sign it manually :)

Comment: it is certainly worth a try... I'd love to hear back how it goes

Comment: They said that if medium trust is too restrictive, then we can order their server hosting :( Trying other provider..

Answer (score 2):

Reflection.Emit which is used by Dapper is not allowed in Medium Trust.

You should find a hosting provider that offers Full Trust.  [discountasp.net](https://www.discountasp.net/) is one I have used before.