# Does Dapper work in medium trust?

Tags: dapper

Just getting started with Dapper. I'd like to use it, but I have to be sure that it will work in a medium-trust server situation. I've googled for answer without any luck.

Thanks.

Comment: This would suggest no : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780278/securityexception-dapper-on-shared-hosting

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, LiamB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SecurityException - Dapper on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780278/securityexception-dapper-on-shared-hosting)

As per the link above, it doesn't look like this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Dapper actually does work but in a limited way.  I've gotten the Get methods to work fine but the updating and inserting seems to be the major problem area so I just manually do those.  Oh well.  I like Dapper too much to drop it completely.